# Change Toolbar overflow menu text colour

Tags: android, xml

I've been trying to work with the new Toolbar and style the overflow menu without much luck.

Currently the overflow menu is showing as white text with an off-white background.

[image]

**I would like to change the overflow menu text colour without affecting the Title and Subtitle in the Toolbar.**

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBarCustomTheme"
    android:popupTheme="@style/popupNew"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    />
```

**style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupNew</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_icons</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/text_icons</item>

    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_icons</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>


<style name="popupNew" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/text_icons</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It just took one additional line under the ActionBarCustomTheme:

```
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
```

It's a bit confusing as there is a property called **textColorPrimary** which has already been set but this property doesn't seem to affect the overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your popup theme to the following:

```
<style name="popupNew" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
</style>
```

You may check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238548/1552622) answer for details.