# How is a context in Android created? What is the purpose of ContextThemeWrapper?

Tags: android, android-context

I'm helping put together this page: [What is a context?](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Context)

To help illustrate how components are related to a `Context`, I created this diagram from looking through the framework source code:

[image: Context Subclasses]

After digging around a bit, I had the following questions:

1. **What creates a `Context` and what concrete classes are used?**  The base `Context` class itself is an abstract class, which requires almost all of its methods to be implemented.  And a `ContextWrapper`, when instantiated, requires a `Context` instance to be passed in as it's base context, so there must be at least one concrete `Context` class.
2. I understand that the `ContextWrapper` and its subclasses utilize the wrapper/decorator pattern to add functionality to the base `Context` class as needed.  **What is the purpose of the `ContextThemeWrapper`?**  It overrides a few methods, but if it's wrapping a base `Context`, why not just delegate the calls to the base `Context`?  For example, the `Activity` class extends `ContextThemeWrapper`, which provides a specific implementation for `getTheme()` and `setTheme()`.  Why?

The Android developer java docs are a bit vague.  E.g., [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html)

Comment: I actually was able to step into an app and found the concrete class that `Activity` and `Application` use as the `mBaseContext`.  It's `ContextImpl`.  https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java

Answer (score 7):

Answering #2:

ContextThemeWrapper adds theming support to a Context, otherwise you can't apply any theme to the Views you create. That's why Activity layouts support themes while widget layouts don't, for example. You can also create a ContextThemeWrapper yourself to override the current theme with another one.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but please tell me what is Activity layout and Widget layout?

Comment: Activity layout means a regular XML layout with Views, widget layout means an XML layout containing remote views, used specifically for home screen widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am very late to the party, but The answer to #1 is I believe the [ContextImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/742a67127366c376fdf188ff99ba30b27d3bf90c/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) class. It is created by the system and then whenever and any class (eg - Activity/Application) calls the `attach` method which takes in a `Context` as an argument and internally calls the `attachBaseContext` of the `ContextWrapper` class to setup the base context, this `ContextImpl` is passed as the `Context` argument.
Thus the `ContextImpl` class provides a solid implementation of the `Context` class.

Answer (score 0):

**What creates a Context and what concrete classes are used?**
[Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context?hl=en) is instantiated by the system using [ContextImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) class under the hood. An [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Activity?hl=en) for example extends [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper?hl=en) and receives a base context object from outside. When you work with a context in Android usually the last one is represented by a chain of `ContextWrapper`s and a `ContextImpl` instance at the head. But `ContextImpl` is an internal class and as an app developer you shouldn't instantiate it manually but treat a `Context` as an abstraction provided by the system. Maybe you'll find this article useful: [Which Context should I use in Android?](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/which-context-should-i-use-in-android-e3133d00772c). What is more important to understand is that a context may be bound to a theme and it leads us to the second question.

**What is the purpose of the ContextThemeWrapper?**
To understand the purpose of the [ContextThemeWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/view/ContextThemeWrapper?hl=en) class it's important to understand what is a *theme overlay*. In short, `ContextThemeWrapper` allows to partially override a *parent* context theme using so called theme overlay. I recommend [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-styling-themes-overlay-1ffd57745207) from Android team which describes theme overlays in details. You can also take a look at another SO question: [When should one use Theme.AppCompat vs ThemeOverlay.AppCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238433/when-should-one-use-theme-appcompat-vs-themeoverlay-appcompat)