# Toolbar's custom text color is not used

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-styles

I'm trying customize the ActionBar in my app. I want to change background color and text color.

My `styles.xml` is as below:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` I added `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`. In my activity I added the action bar with code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar" />
```

In result I have the action bar with correct color but incorrect text color.

What's wrong?

**Note:**
I'm using AppCompat, not Holo or other.

Comment: Where is the `MyActionBar` style? Please update the question with that style.

Comment: @Sufian Oh, sorry. Updated.

Comment: Currently, the text colour is white or black (on ActionBar)?

Comment: It's black. I tried to set another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `Toolbar`'s theme is set to light, hence the Android picks a dark (black) text colour.

You need to update it to following:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextColor">#FF0001</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextColor">#FF0001</item>
    <!-- your other theme attributes -->
</style>
```

**Notes:**

1. For `Toolbar` themes, use `ThemeOverlay` instead of `Theme.AppCompat`. Related - [When should one use Theme.AppCompat vs ThemeOverlay.AppCompat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238433/when-should-one-use-theme-appcompat-vs-themeoverlay-appcompat),
2. replace `#FF0001` with any colour you like. This is the colour of your title text.

Comment: text colour only? Or back arrow too?

Comment: Uhm. I don't see any "back arrow" on action bar.

Comment: Thank you, it works. And line `<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>` is useless now, isn't it?

Comment: One more question. I found what my actionbar popup menu is dark now and text on it is the same colour. It makes me sad. If you know how fix it, please tell.

Comment: @ziwert you need to add this line to your `Toolbar` in XML: `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`. This means that your popup will use light theme.

Comment: @ziwert post your `Toolbar` tag from the XML.

Comment: I added a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362681/actionbar-popup-menu-style

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should remove 
actionBarTabTextStyle
from AppTheme.NoActionBar

hope it will help...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly use

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
```

inside your custom MyActionBar style defination.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `app:theme` i am using `android:theme` which works for me.

Give it a try.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/MyActionBar" />              <----------Here
```

Comment: I think this should solve it.. `titleTextColor` instead of `textColor`
    `<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle"
        parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/actionbar_text_color</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ActionBar text and background color through java code

yourToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
yourToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.YOUR_COLOR);