# Styling toolbar in Android application

Tags: android, android-toolbar, styling

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.andre.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/ToolbarTheme">



    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

But I still have balck title on Toolbar. Why ?

Comment: You should change your custom ToolbarTheme's parent. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39344517/5392118).

Comment: try   `app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"` and more styling info @ http://www.materialdoc.com/toolbars/

Answer (score 0):

Hi try setting the textColor directly to the toolbar. if it works , there is something strange going on in the theme

Comment: `toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);` works fine.

Comment: yes , that would've worked too .. but it only changes the title color :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

This works for me when I want white title in toolbar