# I am getting a red variable error in my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually Gradle version issues. If latest Gradle also does not work, make sure your application goes through Rebuilding/Clean project process. Sometimes amending the Gradle with right version doesn't work because of old cache.

Comment: clean then rebuild geting these error D:\android studio workspace\NIDHIIOT\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\app_bar.xml
Error:(1) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay').
Error:(1) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Comment: @varun pandey Debug gives you the errors.   Just go to your styles directory and insert the variables.  Once you fixed your style/ActionBarThemeOverlay,   it should give you more errors on more other missing values you implemented the code but not in your layout OR it will run completely fine.   I have this issue all the time, it is an easy fix. Just depends on what you've been doing to the coding.

Comment: i m getting R.id error r is getting red and all id's of button are errored with that red r

Comment: Check your package name and androidmanifest to make sure it is correct with Gradle. if that doesn't work, invalidate cache and restart. if that doesn't work, i recommend posting your code up on all places.    Just the activity is not enough to know your issue.

Comment: It was Action bar Theme Overlay problem thank you so much all of you for the help problem resolved :)

Comment: @varun pandey you're very welcome, i'm glad to hear you got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio:
Build--->Clean Project or try 
Tools-->Android-->Sync Project with Gradle Files.
If this doesn't work look for errors in the messages box.

Comment: clean then rebuild geting these error D:\android studio workspace\NIDHIIOT\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\app_bar.xml
Error:(1) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay').
Error:(1) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in the theme you picked.
Go to values--->styles folder, and change your Apptheme parent to ActionBarThemeOverlay. Then find your AppTheme in the theme picker and choose it.

Comment: The R is still red

Comment: my bad the parent should be ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light or one of the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238433/when-should-one-use-theme-appcompat-vs-themeoverlay-appcompat

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio, you have following things to be clear on::

1. Invalidate Cache
2. Clean and Rebuild Project (involves Syncing)
3. Missing SDK for the platform you are using

**Invalidate Cach**

File > Invalidate Cache / Restart

**Clean and Rebuild Project**

a. Build > Clean Project
b. Build > Rebuild Project

**Missing SDK**

- Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Launch Standalone SDK Manager
- Check the Android SDK platform you want to install and use and Install packages

Do the above in order, I guess your problem should be fixed.

P.S. Update Android Studio if the problem persists.