# How can i change the color of ActionBarText

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is my style.xml for now its showing Action Bar Text in black color, if am changing android:titleTextStyle its changing the text color of listView AND many other thing, how can i solve this ?
i want Action bar title color in white and others in black.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/myNavigationColor</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you want to change ActionBar title color runtime??

Comment: There are many solutions already given to this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal your link is invalid, it is on Holo Theme not AppCompat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change ActionBar title text color using Light.DarkActionBar theme in AppCompat 21](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870698/change-actionbar-title-text-color-using-light-darkactionbar-theme-in-appcompat-2)

Comment: The link is not invalid, it is working. And if you know what theme you are using you can always make the desired changes. Nothing is ever on a platter my friend. Good luck.

Comment: you all mean to say that i have to change full style of my project. Right ?

Answer (score 1):

use this on styles.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: i asked for some modification in my code, i dont want to change whole code because this is a big project.