# How to change actionbar textcolor?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason it can't recognise textColor property.

Here's the code i used:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="background">@color/DarkSlateGray</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'.

Comment: set parent to parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" instead of  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" hope that works

Comment: @Shubham Doesn't work. Gives me the same error.

Comment: if your are using toolbar as actionbar this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852108/how-do-you-set-the-title-color-for-the-new-toolbar

Comment: Did you tried giving color as html code, `<item name="textColor">#d1cbf5</item>`

Comment: Check whether my answer solve your problem... @abff

Comment: You will find your answer on this link:
Its a duplicate post[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code)

Comment: @MobilityNewTech It's not dublicate. The link which you gave is actually about giving text color for Action Bar **Programatically** . What he asks is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

Comment: My question is duplicated. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26871541/3140594

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you,

Use this

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
```

instead of this

```
 <item name="textColor">@color/White</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question:

This link will help you through java class
[How to change action bar title color in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920277/how-to-change-action-bar-title-color-in-code)

From style use this
[How do I change the background color of the ActionBar of an ActionBarActivity using XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us)

@Ganesh

Its mentioned in @rnoway answer

```
     <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: Answer only if you are going to provide answer for question. Don't use for saying duplicate or mention some other person.  Use Comment option if you want to say anything other than answer.

Comment: @MobilityNewTech Doesn't give any error but doesn't show any text. The topic is similar but the context is different from other questions posted previously

Comment: @MobilityNewTech I tried programmatically but still doesn't show anything.

Comment: @abff you didn't checked my answer?  I am sure it would work. Give it a try and say what happened in comment.

Comment: @Ganesh My question is duplicated. The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870698/change-actionbar-title-text-color-using-light-darkactionbar-theme-in-appcompat-2