# Change ActionBar text color using AppCompat

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, styles

I'm trying to change ActionBar text color like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>


<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

According to a lot of [similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861661/actionbar-text-color/5881739#5881739) ([another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870698/change-actionbar-title-text-color-using-light-darkactionbar-theme-in-appcompat-2)) this should work, but none of that changes text color and also my ActionBar is becoming transparent when I try this. I can change it's text color by changing textColorPrimary in AppTheme, but it also changes a lot of stuff.

Also I'd like to see any links about how styling works in android cause it and it's hierarchy kinda confuses me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not you using **ToolBar** xml Like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/videos_toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolBarTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/ToolBarColor"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_32sdp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/ThemeColor">
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like ToolBar is really easier to use